# Mouse not working after xubuntu-desktop install

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, mouse, xubuntu

I had a fully functional Ubuntu 11.04 installation on a Gateway LT3103u netbook. I upgraded to 11.10. When I logged in, the screen was all strange: instead of a pointer there was a large pixellated square, the desktop was a series of horizontal and vertical lines, and text was garbled. I used ctrl-alt-1 to use the tty and installed the xubuntu-desktop package on the theory that perhaps the problem I was having was Gnome-specific. Now, however, when I boot the machine, I can't use the mouse on the Ubuntu login screen or after I log in. What do you suggest I try next to approach this problem? Thanks!

**Update**: [Answer to the graphics problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/74602/31455).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You can actually toggle the touchpad with a button on the keyboard. fn-F7 re-enabled the touchpad. I'm still having the graphics issues, but those belong in another thread.